# Jquery onClick not Working by Class Name

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Problem is actually pretty simple , but i don't know why can't i get it to work.
i want to add a classname to my button `on Click` by using its current class `btn-cat`.I am just a student learning not professional so please keep that in mind before make any acquisitions.

Here is the [Link](http://goo.gl/9VQSAF) . where am i wrong?

Note: I can't find any good or valid way to post jsfiddle link that's why i shorten the link to workaround [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192954/cannot-post-a-jsfiddle-link-in-stackoverflow) is **SO** question for that.

Comment: You can't post the jsfiddle.net link because you haven't included any code in your question. Which is what the error message in the screenshot you included in your other question was telling you.

Comment: ok , then how `Nikolay` answered my question without any code? i think link need to be opened before being commented on @nnnnnn

Comment: There is *no code* in your question. There is just a link to an external site that shows code. (Links to jsfiddle.net *are* allowed if you *also* post some relevant code *directly in your question*.)

Comment: why i will post jsfiddle if i write my whole code in or portion of it is question itself ?

Comment: If your code is short, why would you make people navigate to another site to view it when you can just show it here? You are asking for help, so why not make things easier for the people who can provide that help? Including a fiddle is a supplementary thing so people can see the problem live in action if needed, or see a problem function in the context of a larger program. (In any case I don't make the rules, I'm just trying to explain what they are.)

Comment: @BadComputer links rot if you dont include your code in the question  people who will view this question in the future will have no idea what this question is all about. you need to abide by the communities rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `$('this')` to `$(this)`, otherwise you are passing to jQuery a string instead of DOM element in question. Demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/1g01fkew/3/)